# Is it possible to use the eclipse GUI to create a own java application?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I have seen several java programs with the same GUI/layout as eclipse. Is there a way to use this for you own applications?

Comment: Yes there is, search for Eclipse RCP, you will get tutorials for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be used via [swt](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/) and [jface](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFace/article.html) or [Eclipse RCP](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html).